# React, getting Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone help me with React Hooks basics, I am relatively new and couldn't find proper help online

```
import React from 'react'
import { auth, provider } from "../../../firebaseSetup";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"


const GoogleAuth = async() => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

    auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(() => {
      navigate('/home');
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message)
    })
}
export  default GoogleAuth
```

I get error on `const navigate = useNavigate()` saying:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they want for `useNavigate` (and all hooks) is to be called only at the top level of a React component or a custom hook.

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns.

> See [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) for more.

A solution to your problem could be calling `const navigate = useNavigate()` in the component where you will use `GoogleAuth`, and pass `navigate` as parameter.

As an example like so:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { auth, provider } from "../../../firebaseSetup";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"


const GoogleAuth = async(navigate) => {
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(() => {
      navigate('/home');
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message)
    })
}
export  default GoogleAuth
```

```
import GoogleAuth from "GoogleAuth";
const App = ()=>{
       /* 
          here at the top level, not inside an if block,
          not inside a function defined here in the component...
       */
       const navigate = useNavigate(); 
       useEffect(()=>{
         GoogleAuth(navigate)
       },[])
       return <div></div>
    }
export default App;
```

Comment: Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:

✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks.